# after updated jdk version my existed project compile error

Tags: java, maven-3

My old jdk version was 1.8, I update it to 13. But my old project compiled error. This is my pom config.

```
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

But when I changed to this:

```
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>13</source>
                <target>13</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

compiled ok. Why ? I can not change source/target to 13, because others's sdk is 1.8. who could help me, thanks.

This is error message:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.367 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-12-25T19:16:37+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/57M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project live-common: Compilation failure -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :live-common
```

Comment: did you run with clean ? can you add the error here ?

Comment: I ran clean.

```

```

Comment: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project live-common: Compilation failure -> [Help 1]

Comment: pls attach mvn clean install -X > log.txt output

Comment: I did , but can not find out error still .

Answer (score 0):

definition looks fine, also by [this site](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/maven-error-release-version-1-13-not-supported/)
maybe try 3 options:

1) to comment out most of your code until build pass.
and then try to uncomment it block by block until you find the problematic place.

2) or to configure the IDE for version 13 and see if it finds errors.

3) to run maven clean with debug level (-X), it might provide more details on the error.

Comment: @fengsmith, did you try to comment out all the code and run ?
then you will know if issue  related to the code or to project definition

Comment: No, I did not . Thank you, later I rollback jdk version to 8.